# Edit/Cancel Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where the user can edit their text. I want the user to be able to retrieve their text if they delete it by hitting the cancel button.

How would I be able to retrieve a users text if they edit the original text, and when they press cancel the original text in the form before the edit comes back?

Comment: Store original text in some hidden field or retrieve it form db (if you store it there)

Comment: I'm presuming you mean, if they edit something here before hitting cancel you want it to restore what was originally there if they hit cancel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following could be built upon so that they could make multiple changes and still have the previous text available on change.

// JavaScript source code

```
var orginalText = "Please Enter Some Text here";
var newTest = "";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#target").change(function () {
        newText = this.text;
    });

    $(".cancel").on("click", function () {
        $("#target").text(orginalText);
    });
});
```

Comment: What if the original text was stored in a database? Would I do something similar?

Comment: You would simply make the `orginalText` equal to the value of the target field at the start.

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused how would I do that exactly?

Comment: It's not a problem, `var orginalText = document.getElementById("#foo").innerText;`  Will story the current value into the variable.

Comment: Hey sorry, but last question. I have something like this: 
`$('.cancel, .email-item').click(function() {
 $('.email-content-body').text(original_text);
        $('.email-content-body').attr("contenteditable", "false");
 $('.email-content-body').css({color: "black"});
        $('.cancel').css({display: "none"});
        $('.delete').css({display: "inline"});
        $('.submitbranch').css({display: "none"});
        $('.edit').css({display: "inline"});
 
    })`
But the cancel button still doesnt revert the original text, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/LiamDotPro/448b8a6fe409bc2d1f525e3a7106cbfa You'll need to also make sure this function is within a $(document).ready().

Comment: Are you able to provide me with a jsfiddle so I can try and figure it out for you?

Comment: I can't really because this function is kind of part of a larger webapp and I would have to include most of that but I can provide you with screenshots if thats possible.

Comment: Is it an open source application or a local version? Screenshots probably won't help really :/

Comment: Oh nvm I got it. Thanks! I have no idea why it suddenly started working now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `data-*` attributes to do this by adding `data-original-text` to the input like :

```
<input name='first_input' data-original-text='First input text' value="First input text"/>
```

And add a click event to the `cancel` button that will get the data attribute and assign it to the value :

```
$('form').on('click','#cancel',function(){
  $(this).closest('form').find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).data('original-text'));
  })
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('form').on('click','#cancel',function(){
  $(this).closest('form').find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).data('original-text'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name='first_input' data-original-text='First input original text' value="First input original text"/>
  <input name='second_input' data-original-text='Second input original text' value="Second input original text"/>

  <button id='cancel'>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey sorry, but last question. I have something like this: 
`$('.cancel, .email-item').click(function() { $('.email-content-body').text(original_text); $('.email-content-body').attr("contenteditable", "false"); $('.email-content-body').css({color: "black"}); $('.cancel').css({display: "none"}); $('.delete').css({display: "inline"}); $('.submitbranch').css({display: "none"}); $('.edit').css({display: "inline"}); })` But the cancel button still doesnt revert the original text, where am I going wrong?